# link with dhtmlxGrid is not working

Tags: javascript, json, dhtmlx

I have been struggling to get a link to appear with dhtmlxGrid. I can get the example working just fine but when I try to get a link to appear it doesn't. According to what I read, you can use JSON and display links.

I have made a pastie that shows the code and this should work assuming you pull in the Javascript libraries.

http://pastie.org/private/35znvuxwkvxzm4xvgpvva

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Duh!

Make sure you set the ColType to link:

mygrid.setColTypes("ro,link");

*double facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

You can create link manually and in your json and call javascript function on your  link...

```
data = {total_count:1,rows: [{"id":"30","data":["30","0","parent-P0004","<a href=javascript
:showDetailMeetAssReport('P0004');>14</a>","14"]}]}
```

Then create javascript function to perform operation on link:

```
 showDetailMeetAssReport(usercode){}
```

No need to give setcoltype link,you can set it ro.